# Using same BroadcastReceiver type multiple times in one project?

Tags: android, performance, broadcastreceiver

Would it be a bad approach to define multiple broadcast receivers in your project (huge, structured,different modules) which actually do exactly the same or should I do everything to wrap those receivers together to one though performance reasons or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Performance should not be affected. Usually, having multiple duplicate hunks of code increases maintenance costs, and so you may wish to consolidate them for that reason.